# Reformating Routes for controller's actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

I am working on a rails application. Its rendering controller name, action and id in url like

```
localhost:3000/content/video/2-page-item
```

So, I wish to remove the controller and action with the other name like

```
localhost:3000/video/2-page-item
```

my controller that i am using is content and the action is video. I tried using the following codes in routes

```
match "video" => "content#video", :as => "video", :via => [:get, :post]
```

I get the following URL format

```
localhost:3000/video?id=2-page-item
```

Is it possible to get the above URL format as

```
localhost:3000/video/2-page-item
```

Comment: Add your complete routes code here. Atleast for videos

Answer (score 0):

you can override the Rail's to_param to method in the relative model to generate a parameterize url.

I assume you have a model called Content and attribute description for Content model. For example if you have following record

Content id => 2, description => 'page item' results will be video/2-page-item

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    def to_param
        [id, description.parameterize].join("-")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change route like this:-

```
match '/video/:id' => "content#video", :as => "video", :via => [:get, :post]
```